# Object of class Illuminate\Support\Fluent could not be converted to int

Tags: sql, database, laravel, schema

I'm trying to add column to existing table using Schema::table, but whatever I do I'm getting following error:

> "Object of class Illuminate\Support\Fluent could not be converted to int"

Point is that I can't use migration to update the table as tables are created upon user registration and columns are added depending of their choices (15-20 choices)

Here is the code I'm using for this:

```
Schema::table($new->id, function ($table2) {
-
            $table2->string('choice_one')->default('0');
            $table2->string('choice_two')->default('0');
            $table2->string('choice_three')->default('0');
            $table2->string('choice_four')->default('0');
        });
```

I tried searching everywhere but I couldn't find solution for this.

Comment: table name should be single (like: user_choices) and create column user_id on that table and store id of users table on this table. It should be something like this.

Comment: Table names are single, table names are ID from users table so it's always unique

Comment: `Schema::table` structure need `first` param as string and second is Closure. But you are providing `integer` in first param that causing error. check details here https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/migrations#columns

Answer (score 0):

Try passing a string instead an integer like

```
Schema::table('t_'.$new->id, function ($table2) {
-
            $table2->string('choice_one')->default('0');
            $table2->string('choice_two')->default('0');
            $table2->string('choice_three')->default('0');
            $table2->string('choice_four')->default('0');
        });
```

this way you could pass a string and reference the `table` in the future by the `id`

Comment: Tried this, but it's showing me same error and laravel is highlighting below line:

   `$table2->string('choice_one')->default('0');`

Any idea?

Comment: Ok here are some questions
You use Schema::table to update the schema?
Are you returning the Schema::table block of code? 
If you are creating the schema why are you not using Schema::create?
if you could show more of your code we could may have a better understanding

Comment: Yes, I'm using Schema::table to update existing table. I created table with schema::create when user registers first time. Based of setting user choose I need to update table to add columns with their selected choices. It's something like: If user select choice_one update their table and add column with name choice_one. Let me know if you need more explanation

Answer (score 0):

OK, so worst coder nightmare happened. I had '-' left in code so it was trying to pass it to table. Everything is working once I removed it. 2 days of life gone